# Create Git Branch from local Project folder

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, gitlab

there is our little project set-up nicely in VisualStudio and GitLab. One of the developers did´nt know how to branch and started programming locally, decoupled from our repo. Just to be clear, none of us are professional programmers. The question is how can I re-introduce this local folder as a real branch to our existing project. Is there a best practice?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,
mulm

Comment: I guess you could try adding a remote on this repo that the developer used to get a "sight" of the common branches used to develop by the whole team and then cherry-pick whatever the developer did on his/her own on top of the common branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I understand this correctly,

You already have a repo, you just want to add a new folder to it. Correct?

Then, you do git init in the parent folder that contains the new folder.

Then git add origin linktoyourrepo

git fetch

git pull origin master.

Then you should get the difference between the two branches.

Also, if this doesn't work, you can move the folder out,

git clone linktoyourrepo

and add the folder back to this repo. This will show the difference in local vs repo.

Hope this helps. Cheers